# Symfony2 FOSUser custom validation not working

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i'm using Symfony 2.8 and FOSUser bundle 2.0 for my user management.
I'm trying to create custom validator for phone number field without success.

This is my code:

UserBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml

```
<class name="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User">
   <property name="phoneNumber">
        <constraint name="Acme\UserBundle\Validator\Constraint\IsConfirmedPhonenumber">
             <option name="groups">
                     <value>Acme</value>
              </option>
         </constraint>
    </property>
 </class>
```

Service definition

```
<service class="Acme\UserBundle\Validator\Constraint\IsConfirmedPhonenumberValidator" id="acme_user.validator.is_confirmed_phonenumber_validator">
    <argument id="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" type="service"/>
    <tag name="acme.constraint_phonenumber"/>
 </service>
```

On my form type

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
     $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        'intention'  => 'profile',
    ));
}
```

My custom constraint

```
class IsConfirmedPhonenumber extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The phonenumber "%phonenumber%" is not verified.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return "acme.constraint_phonenumber";
    }
}
```

And validator

```
class IsConfirmedPhonenumberValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the passed value is valid.
     *
     * @param mixed $value The value that should be validated
     * @param Constraint $constraint The constraint for the validation
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $phoneVerificationRepo = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeCoreBundle:PhoneVerification');

        $phoneVerificationRepo->findBy(array('phoneNumber' => $value, 'verified' => true));

        if(!$phoneVerificationRepo)
        {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('%phonenumber%', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

This configuration doesn't work for me since validate method in my custom validator never gets called.

Comment: Did you properly cleared the cache? Modifications to `validation.xml` generally need to be "recompiled" to take effects.

Comment: Yes, multiple times :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by specifying validation groups in createForm factory method in overridden editAction method of ProfileController.

```
$form = $formFactory->createForm(['validation_groups' => array('AcmeProfile', 'Profile')]);
```

Setting validation groups in config or custom FormType didn't help either since i'm overriding FOS factory and ProfileController editAction.

Answer (score 1):

In your service definition, your tag name is wrong, it should be `validator.constraint_validator` to be registered as a `Validator`.

```
<service class="Acme\UserBundle\Validator\Constraint\IsConfirmedPhonenumberValidator" id="acme_user.validator.is_confirmed_phonenumber_validator">
    <argument id="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" type="service"/>
        <tag name="validator.constraint_validator" />
 </service>
```

And your constraint should be configured using the `id` of your validator service, therefor:

```
class IsConfirmedPhonenumber extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The phonenumber "%phonenumber%" is not verified.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return "acme_user.validator.is_confirmed_phonenumber_validator";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right about the tag. That fixes the issue with validator.